# How to pass .jpg url to index.php in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url-routing

My Yii2 application generates urls like this:
http://example.com/map-image/1-map.jpg
This is not a real jpg file but a dynamically generated jpg image. But nginx returns 404 error.

I want to pass /map-image/1-map.jpg to /index.php so that it can process the request.

If I remove .jpg from the url settings in Yii2 then it works. i.e. http://example.com/map-image/1-map works.

My nginx config is:

```
location / {        
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: There must be another `location` in your configuration that is handling URIs which end with `.jpg`, probably a regular expression like `location ~ \.jpg$`

Comment: Thanks this solution worked